# Program that fetches all music album images and saves them as ID3 tag

Tags: gratis, images, music, id3

I'm looking for a software (Windows or Linux) or an Android application that, given a folder, automatically and batch fetch the albums covers, and then write them down **as ID3 tag**.

It should support MP3 and FLAC and be free.

Comment: I know iTunes will try to find the album art covers if there are any missing. I don't know what other formats they support, however.

Answer (score 1):

Try [MusicBee](http://getmusicbee.com). It has a "download artwork" feature which should do the trick for you provided you have the correct ID3 tags. It is a Windows software and it [should support flac](http://getmusicbee.com/forum/index.php?topic=7846.0).